# Cannot disable forced dark mode in my app by system even by using light theme. how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-layout

To moderators: this is not a duplicate question. I've tried all avail. solutions from StackOverflow.

I've used Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionbar as a parent theme in styles.xml file.

my styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00000000</item>
        <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbar</item>


    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/MySnackbar</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

My application class code:

```
public class Extendit extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
           
    }
}
```

The application class is attached in the manifest file. Also, the AppTheme is the base theme of application.

androidmanifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".Extendit"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="df"
        android:icon="@mipmap/iconx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/iconx"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

I've also added "forcedarkallowed" false flag in styles.xml and deleted the styles.xml(night) file.

P.S. I'm using Realme device.

Comment: "I'm using Realme device" -- have you tried anything else? Perhaps Realme is doing something unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Got the fact. The issue is with device and Realme Android 9.0 OS. It doesn't allow you to have your own day or night theme in any way, rather it forces you to have what the system is currently having.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```

And in your AppTheme use this in parent:

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Comment: "<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>" this is already added in apptheme @3rd row. still no luck..

Comment: Try copy and paste all the code from styles.xml (day) to styles.xml (night).